Anomalous Relationship Between Margin and Price in Transaction Data
I’m working with a dataset for a project. Unfortunately, I don’t have access to detailed information about the variables (apart from the descriptions I'll provide below).
After cleaning the data a bit (it was a real mess), I’m left with this dataset, which I’ll link here (along with a screenshot).
One of the variables is called "margin," defined as "cumulative customer margin." This makes me think the variable should be in absolute value. Then, I have two other variables: "price" and "number of transactions."
When filtering for number of transactions = 1, I’d expect the values of price to always be higher than margin (assuming margin = price - cost). However, I’ve found many anomalous values. I’m attaching a few examples in the screenshot.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
Here is the translation of the table:



Variable Data Challenge
Description




EVENT_ID
Transaction ID


N_ITEMS
Total number of items purchased in the transaction


PROP_CONBINI
Proportion of "conbini" articles in the transaction


FAV_GENRE
Preferred manga genre


PHONE_NUMBER
Customer's phone number available


MAIL
Customer's e-mail address


YEAR
Transaction year


MONTH
Transaction month


PAYMENT_TYPE
Agreed payment method


BOOKS_PAID
Number of manga paid for in previous transactions


PRICE
Transaction price


N_SUBSCRIPTIONS
Number of active manga series subscriptions


SUBSCR_CANC
Number of canceled manga series subscriptions in the past


POINT_OF_SALE
Point of sale


AGE
Customer's age


DAYS_FROM_PROMO
Days since the last promo launch


MARGIN
Cumulative customer margin


N_TRANSACTIONS
Total number of transactions made by the customer


CUSTOMER_SINCE
Date of the customer's first transaction


DATE_LAST_PURCHASE
Date of the customer's last transaction


PAID
Amount paid (target variable)



screenshot
Does anyone have any ideas? Am I missing something about the "margin" variable?
I’ve also considered the possibility that it represents a relative value, but when I check the values of margin, there are many instances greater than 100, which doesn’t seem possible.
i didn't find any significant pattern with the other variables
This variable is crucial for me because I need to infer the average cost, which I plan to use as a weight for false negatives (I’m building a classification model for credit scoring, where 1 = pays, 0 = doesn’t pay).
Any suggestions or insights would be incredibly helpful!
